# suppose a vector satisfies $ \ \ u^{H} u = 1 $

Tags: matrices

**Suppose a vector satisfies $ \ \  u^{H} u = 1 \ \ $ . Show that the matrix $ \ \ R=I-2uu^{H} \ \ $ is both unitary and Hermitian. Where $ \ u^{H} \ $ denotes the conjugates transpose of u. Also what is the geometric interpretation if $ uu^{H}$  is a projection .** $$ $$ I have done in the following way- $ R=I-2uu^{H} \ \ implies \ \ R^{H}=(I-2uu^{H})^{H}=I-2(u^{H})^{H} u^{H}=I-2uu^{H}=R . \\ So , R^{H}=R . \ Hence \ R \ is \ Hermitian.  But \ how \ I \ show \ that \ R \ is \ Unitary. Help \ please $

Comment: What’s your definition of a unitary matrix?

Comment: Ok, I now have shown that it is unitary but would  you interpret the geometric meaning of $ R=I-uu^{H} $  if $ uu^{H} $ is a projection as in the question

Comment: Yes, but can you? Hint: if $uu^H$ is orthogonal projection onto $u$, then what is $I-uu^H$?

Comment: is it  a reflection through the subspace on which $ uu^{H} $ is a projection ?

Comment: Not quite. $uu^H$ projects onto $u$, so $I-uu^H$ projects onto its orthogonal complement. Write $v=(I-uu^H)v+(uu^H)v$, and $Rv=(I-uu^H)v-(uu^H)v$, that is, $R$ reverses the component parallel to $u$. This is a reflection, but what’s the reflection boundary?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already shown that $R$ is Hermitian, it follows that
$$ R^HR=R^2=(I-2uu^H)^2=I-4uu^H+4uu^Huu^H=I-4uu^H+4u(u^Hu)u^H $$
$$ =I-4uu^H+4uu^H=I $$
Therefore $R$ is unitary.

The geometric interpretation is that $R$ is the reflection about the hyperplane orthogonal to $u$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) for more information.